# AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> always return 0

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

```
private class notesdb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              //displayProgressBar("Downloading...");
           }

           @Override
           protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
               db.getCount();
               result = db.getCount();

              return result;
           }



           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
              super.onPostExecute(result);
              Log.e(result+"",result+"");
              if(result==null){
                  Log.e("db","empty")
              }else{
                  Log.e("db","not empty")
              }

              //dismissProgressBar();
           }
           }



int result = 0;
new notesdb().onPostExecute(result);


public int getCount() {

        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NOTES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();

        return count;
    }
```

i have this aynctask that check database if null or not but when i run it always return the same value always empty what is wrong in this code?any idea

UPDATE:

```
private class notesdb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
              //super.onPreExecute();
              //displayProgressBar("Downloading...");
           }

           @Override
           protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
               db.getCount();
               int result = db.getCount();

              return result;
           }



           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
             // super.onPostExecute(result);
              Log.e(result+"",result+"");
              if(result==null){
                  Log.e("db","empty");
              }else{
                  Log.e("db","not empty");
              }

              //dismissProgressBar();
           }
           }

Button..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new notesdb().execute();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is db.getCount(); ?

Comment: count of entry in database

Comment: where you write code ?

Comment: have you call execute() ?

Comment: int result = 0;
new notesdb().onPostExecute(result); is only code i have i dont have execute i have this on Oncreate..

Comment: @HakHak where you write DB code? and not getting you

Comment: @HakHak put a log in getCount() method to see what you get from the database too.

Comment: @LazyNinja log cat did not show because of processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);

Comment: You should post a stack trace.

Comment: ok sir wait.i will rerun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `super.onPreExecute();`

Remove the call to `super.onPostExecute(result);`

Also remove these lines:

```
int result = 0;
new notesdb().onPostExecute(result);
```

Create a new notesdb AsyncTask like this:

```
new notesdb().execute();
```

If it's still returning 0, make sure that your database table is populated.

Comment: now i get the same error as before i get this  processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly); error when i use .execute

Comment: Where are you making this call: `new notesdb().execute()` ?  In `onCreate()`?

Comment: Are you certain that the database table is populated?

Comment: you are correct sir because of the processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly); i wasnt aware that i get null pointer on database thanks to Lazy Ninja i was able to determine that i get a null pointer you get the +1 sir

Comment: one more question in this same activity can i put another asynctask for different database?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 1):

Start your async task with

```
new notesdb().execute();
```

instead of

```
new notesdb().onPostExecute(result);
```

Comment: Just pointing where you are doing wrong! It is not the way to call an AsyncTask

Comment: what is the cause why i get this error processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);?

Comment: sir one question the thing i did on preference will it affect my sample program in anyway if i put it on real device?how can i fix that problem?

Comment: @HakHak I dont think it will cause a problem.